# Function doesnt work in Firefox but works in Chrome

Tags: javascript, function, google-chrome, firefox

Function doesnt work in Firefox but it works in Chrome and Internet explorer and in Micrisoft Edge, please help

```
function myFunctionN() 
{
  var filter = event.target.value.toUpperCase();
    var rows = document.querySelector("#tablenew").rows;

    for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var firstCol = rows[i].cells[0].textContent.toUpperCase();
        var secondCol = rows[i].cells[1].textContent.toUpperCase();
        var thirdCol = rows[i].cells[2].textContent.toUpperCase();
        var fourtCol = rows[i].cells[3].textContent.toUpperCase();
        var fiftCol = rows[i].cells[4].textContent.toUpperCase();

        if (firstCol.indexOf(filter) > -1
        || secondCol.indexOf(filter) > -1 
        || thirdCol.indexOf(filter) > -1
        || fourtCol.indexOf(filter) > -1
        || fiftCol.indexOf(filter) > -1
        )
        {
            rows[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            rows[i].style.display = "none";
        }      
    }
}
```

html/php code, there is no data in here cos its in DB echo fetch_data is fetching into table

```
    <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunctionN()" placeholder="Search For Anything.." title="Type, What Ever You Looking For">
            <div class="table-responsive">  
                 <table id="tablenew" class="table table-bordered">  
                      <tr>  
                           <th width="5%">ID</th>  
                           <th width="30%">Name</th>  
                           <th width="10%">Gender</th>  
                           <th width="45%">Designation</th>  
                           <th width="10%">Age</th>  
                      </tr>  
                 <?php  
                 echo fetch_data();  
                 ?>  
                 </table>  
                 <br />  

            </div>
```

[error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07ndS.png)

Comment: Which versions of Firefox, Chrome and Edge are you using?

Comment: Whats is the error in console? what is `event` here?

Comment: It seems you’re using `event` without defining it. Use it as an argument like this: `function myFunctionN(event){`…`}`.

Comment: It would help if you could include the relevant HTML so we can test this out for ourselves

Comment: Firefox 53.0, Chrome 58, Edge 38, IE 11. I dont get any Errors, just doesnt work. Should filter the table but its not doing anything.

Comment: HTML file is huge not sure which part to post, cos there is HTML PHP and the table is from DB...

Comment: @RolandasVizbara Could you post just the #tablenew and anything inside it? Just enough for us to be able to replicate this on our computers.

Comment: @Xufox i added event between the brackets and its not workignat all, not sure what if u mean anything else

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Xufox added picture, second part of your comment, no idea what u want..

Answer (score 0):

@Xufox - your attitude was really bad bro, but you were on the right track with that event thing... I am not programmer, so the way you said didn’t mean anything to me, but after trying five hundred different combinations :) finally got it, so @Xufox... basically added event in the script function myFunction04(event) and event in html onkeyup="myFunction04(event)"... Problem solved. Thank You